# Какое максимальное количество элементов можно поместить в HashMap?

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap

Какое максимальное количество элементов можно поместить в HashMap?
Чтобы проверить Пробовал добавлять Элементы через цикл , но закончилась ОЗУ

Comment: Та у меня той озу 8гб ) Оно даже за размер Инта не вышло )

Comment: Все зависит от коэффициента загрузки по умолчанию (0,75). Вообще на сколько помню, `HashMap` использует массив, который является степенью 2-ки - это `2^30` = `1 073 741 824` * `loadFactor`. Но где-то были споры, что нет ограничений или упиралось в оперативку и разрядность. Тут спорная ситуация.

Comment: У всех коллекций есть метод `size()` и он типа `int`. И этим все сказано

Answer (score 0):

Ну, вообще, в HashMap есть массив, в который пихаются значения. А максимальный размер массива - около 2.14 миллиарда. Так что, за размер можете не беспокоиться.

Вот исходный код одной реализации HashMap([тык](http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.com/2015/10/create-own-hashmap.html)), где все сразу видно.

Comment: зачем вы приводите ссылку на какую-то явно нестандартную реализацию?

Comment: @timbars Неужели в ключевых аспектах(типа, в чем хранятся данные) она отличается от реального HashMap?

Comment: Просто вы говорите что это исходный код HashMap... Напишите что это пример реализации, например

Comment: @timbars согласен, уместное замечание